# Why is there both a tf.round and a tf.rint function in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

Tensorflow has two functions to round a number to its closest integer, [`tf.round`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/round) and [`tf.rint`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/rint).

As far as I can tell, those functions are doing the same thing, but they operate on different type sets, which makes none of them more general than the other (for example `tf.rint` can operate on `tf.bfloat`, while `tf.round` can operate on... `tf.int32`?!?).

So,

- Why do we have two functions operating on different types rather than just one operating on all types?
- Why do we need a `tf.round` operating on `tf.int32` and `tf.int64` anyway?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [this issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/709), it seems that two different people just happened to write the function

Comment: My bad. I looked at just one of the three examples.
Thanks for the clarification @user2357112

Comment: Should I go ahead and delete the answer?

Comment: Yeah, it's wrong, and it's not going to help anyone. Deletion would be best.

Comment: Looking at [this issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/709), it seems that two different people just happened to write the function

Answer (score -1):

```
For tf.round
    x = tf.constant([0.9, 2.5, 2.3, 1.5, -4.5])
    tf.round(x)  # [ 1.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, -4.0 ]

For tf.rint
    x = tf.constant([-1.7, -1.5, -0.2, 0.2, 1.5, 1.7, 2.0]) 
    tf.rint(x)   # [-2., -2., -0., 0., 2., 2., 2.]
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.